# Detail Meshing for Airfoil Forepart

Tags: analysis, ansys

I study on this airfoil and ı want to detail meshing on **forepart**. Actually my element quality was good for in this mesh but ı dont want to red ared on this airfoil. In addition to, ı want to hear all of your ideas. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtsg7.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you are providing very little information on what you are trying to achieve (Is this a structural, fluid or thermal problem? ) I can only guess:

- Increasing the element count on the edge could produce less skewed elements.
- In reality the edge is probalby not sharp but has some kind of chamfer. Try to model it accordingly